# Can CoreBluetooth be used to connect to a Google Home or Amazon Echo (non Bluetooth LE devices) as a peripheral?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I am using an iPhone as my central. Is it possible to use CoreBluetooth to connect to a Google Home, Amazon Echo, or really any non Bluetooth LE devices as a peripheral in order to read said peripheral's RSSI? I do not need to connect to access any services; I'm doing a research project, and simply need to be able to use an iPhone as a sensor for RSSI values, so to speak. Right now I have this code, which scans for and discovers peripherals that are advertising indiscriminately.

```
//
//  BLEManager.swift
//  RSSIappSwiftUI
//
//  Created by bee-mcc on 3/30/21.
//

import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth


//will hold the information needed about Our Peripherals
struct Peripheral: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let rssi: Int
}

class BLEManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate{
    
    //the object that represents the Bluetooth controls of the iphone
    var myCentral: CBCentralManager!
    @Published var peripherals = [Peripheral]()
    
    //var letting us know if myCentral has bluetooth switched on
    @Published var isSwitchedOn = false
    
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        myCentral = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        myCentral.delegate = self
    }
    
    //this is called whenever the central manager updates its state
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            isSwitchedOn = true
        }
        else {
            isSwitchedOn = false
        }
    }
    
    //this is called any time a central manager discovers any peripherals
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        
        var peripheralName: String!
       
        if let name = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as? String {
            peripheralName = name
        }
        else {
            peripheralName = "Unknown"
        }
       
        let newPeripheral = Peripheral(id: peripherals.count, name: peripheralName, rssi: RSSI.intValue)
        print(newPeripheral)
        peripherals.append(newPeripheral)
    }
    
    
    //buttons to start and stop scanning
    func startScanning() {
         print("startScanning")
         myCentral.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
     }
    
    func stopScanning() {
        print("stopScanning")
        myCentral.stopScan()
    }
    
    
    

}
```

I would like to somehow be able to connect to a bluetooth device by specifying it's MAC address in the code somewhere, and then to collect the device with that MAC address's RSSI with regards to the iPhone.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Core Bluetooth only supports BLE (there are some small exceptions to that, but "classic Bluetooth audio" is not one of them). That said, you don't need to connect to get RSSI. It's entirely in the advertising packet. So if you're seeing a callback to `didDiscover`, then it's advertising BLE. You absolutely cannot base this on the MAC, however. iOS explicitly hides that information from the app. There is no general and reliable way to identify a specific Bluetooth device in iOS. The only way is going to be device-specific (if the manufacturer offers something, which I don't think these do).

Comment: My recommendation is to download nRF Connect and use that to scan. See what information is available from these devices. That'll set the ground-rules for what your app can do. (LightBlue is another nice app for this, though I've been finding nRF a bit more useful.)